# Append to vector

Tags: matlab

I have a 2000x1 vector called A and want to add another 2000x1, vector B, to the first one. The idea is to create a 2000x2 matrix.

I'm using the following code:

A= [A; B];

The result I'm getting is a 4000x1 vector though. Can anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: `A = [A B];`....

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB the first dimension of a matrix is interpreted as the number of rows and the `[_;_]` is the vertical stacking operator, so if you have

```
size(A) == [2000 1]
size(B) == [2000 1]
```

then

```
size([A;B]) == [4000 1]
```

and

```
size([A B]) == [2000 2]
```

so to get a 2000x2 matrix you need to concatenate the two vectors with the `[_ _]` operator as `[A B]`

Answer (score 2):

You want to perform horizontal concatenation of two arrays. There are two ways to solve your problem.

1) As Dmitri Chubarov stated: `A = [A B]` will give you the desired result.

2) There is a function `horzcat` which does the same thing. `A = horzcat(A, B);`

Concatenation in the other direction is achieved by the means as `Z = vertcat(A, B);` and `Z = [A; B];`